# Automate Linux software installations

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation, unzip

I have a set of steps I follow in Linux which are as follows :

1. Unzip a folder located at path /home/xyzuser/temp/File.zip to /home/xyzuser/source/
2. I then navigate to source using "cd /home/xyzuser/source/File"
3. I find the listing of folders here using "find . -type d > hierarchy.txt"
4. Remove a few directories in hierarchy.txt that are more than 5 folders deep .

   For example , if there is /level1/level2/level3/level4/level5/thisShouldBeRemoved , I manually delete this entry from the hierarchy.txt file
5. Now copy a third python file from  /home/xyzuser/temp/ to /home/xyzuser/source/File. I make a few changes in this Python file and run it.
6. Then I issue a command to execute a 3rd party tool in the command line.

   I worked with Java and don't really see how to automate this in Java. But I feel shell , Perl or Python would help develop a single script which I can run to automate this entire process. Can anyone give me a direction where I should begin exploring to start this stuff. Is there any way of packaging the above Linux commands I give in the terminal and running them at once?

Comment: I feel they would help too. You should ask some Linux system administrators (over on another site).

Comment: I think that this question is too broad. If you have a specific question about one of these steps, maybe you could ask about that, showing what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Instead of just describing what you'd like to get done, I think you should do some programming on your own, maybe shell scripting for example, and then ask more specific questions when you get stuck. The community appreciates effort show in terms of code, so you're much more likely to get helpful comments and answers if you show us some code.

Comment: Look into [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/). It provides means with which to automate all of the steps you've listed if you have SSH access to the target machine.

Comment: Sure , will post the shell scripts I am trying to write , thank you

Answer (score 0):

read manual for unzip, cd, cp, mv for all other steps

for step 4 you can use the following code

```
    for line in $(find . -type d)
        do
            levels=`echo $line|grep -o "/"|wc -l `
            if [ $levels -le 5 ] then 
                echo $line >> hierarchy.txt
            fi
        done
```